# What questions should I ask to client before to start PSD 2 XHTML work?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, wireframe, psd

I have a PSD design file for **fixed width site** which I'm converting to accessible cross browser xhtml markup. It is not my design and I cannot write server side coding (php, asp.net, etc). My job is to write only XHTML, CSS and javascript/jquery if needed.

What questions should I ask my client before starting the work?

**Edit:**

1. Client want Template should be compatible to all A Grade browsers  http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/
2. and Code should be compatible with screen reader and WCAG 2.0 compatible.
3. He want if i use javascript then without javascript at least site should be function-able and accessible

Comment: I want to get all info from client at once to complete project on time without re-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Behavior, such as :hover, :focus, animation, etc. are important with PSDs, because they're not obvious.
2. Are there any concessions the client will be willing to make for certain browsers in order to fulfill for example WCAG requirements? Your work needs to comply, but does the designer's work also comply?
3. Contingency design: if there are forms, and/or if something goes wrong, what should happen? How should that look? Is there a design for it?
4. Is it clear what things will be handled server-side and what the client wants handled client-side?
5. Be careful with charging more for IE6. If you're worth your salt with CSS and use a good reset, it shouldn't really be much of an issue as far as layout/bugs go.
6. DO discuss what subtle differences are acceptable for IE6 and some other browsers: normal corners instead of rounded corners? Transparency? etc. Some of these things WILL take more time to make work for IE6, and may have performance implications.
7. Put it on paper, have them sign it, and have them be explicit.
8. Agree to this: if it's not EXPLICITLY requested/mentioned in the contract, it's not part of your work, because you haven't had an opportunity to estimate costs for it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: nice list :) Although I do think I'm good with CSS and use good resets, then again point 7 covers most of my issues with IE6 :P Finding a consensus on graceful degradation/progressive enhancement would be a good start.

Comment: Sure. The whole idea is to be as explicit as you can, ask the client to be as explicit as they can (whether it's about IE6 or whatever it may be), and agree to do only that which you've explicitly agreed to. You can't go wrong with that, and the clent can hire you for more details as they come.

Answer (score 2):

What browsers does he want it to work in? Double the price if everything has to work in IE6.

Also, do you know what has to happen when certain parts of content are overflowing?

Comment: he want to make site compatible to all A grade browser http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/ IE6 is also in A grade browser list

Comment: ugh, I hate that IE6 is still on there, but fair enough.

Comment: but what reason i can give to pay extra for one browser?

Comment: because in broad terms (and I'm oversimplifying) if you get something to work in one grade A browser it works for 95% in the other grade A browsers. Except IE6, in which only 50% will work. 
To make sure IE6 gets it all you'll have to do a lot more work.

Answer (score 2):

Ask him everything that couldn't fit into a PSD file: animations, client-side data validation, what to do on events, what to do on mouseovers, what to do on overflow, how much speed is an issue (this will effect asset compression, file formats, etc), if he wants the code commented.

Answer (score 0):

A wireframe should provide all the static information: colors, layout, proportions, etc. What you can't tell from a wireframe is the dynamic stuff: link hover styles, menu flyouts, animations, etc.

Comment: Eh, that's what I meant. I often use the terms interchangeably, though technically I guess they're not.